# filter dateframe by certain date

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I have a csv file containing dates in german format:

```
date,D11,D21,D31,D41
19.03.2018 00:00:00,6,4,6,2
19.03.2018 01:00:00,5,8,5,1
20.03.2018 00:00:00,2,2,3,0
20.03.2018 01:00:00,2,5,4,1
21.03.2018 00:00:00,3,7,8,3
21.03.2018 01:00:00,18,22,19,3
22.03.2018 00:00:00,32,69,47,10
22.03.2018 01:00:00,105,105,69,32
23.03.2018 00:00:00,117,134,106,57
23.03.2018 01:00:00,97,83,95,73
```

I want to get rows by certain dates. In order to get this output:

```
date,D11,D21,D31,D41
21.03.2018 00:00:00,3,7,8,3
21.03.2018 01:00:00,18,22,19,3
```

I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.read_csv('myData.csv')
df.loc[datetime.date(year=2018,month=3,day=21):datetime.date(year=2018,month=3,day=21)]
```

Unfortunately, I am getting a TypeError:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'date' of 'datetime.datetime' object needs an argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `datetime` objects, it doesn't play nicely with Pandas. You can just use strings:

```
# read csv
df = pd.read_csv('myData.csv',
                 index_col=['date'], parse_dates=True)

df.loc['2018-03-21':'2018-03-22']
```

Or if you want just rows with date `2018-03-21`:

```
df.loc['2018-03-21']
```

Output:

```
                     D11  D21  D31  D41
date                                   
2018-03-21 00:00:00    3    7    8    3
2018-03-21 01:00:00   18   22   19    3
```